# NodeJS, Express: forked child process is unable to make use of pool for bulk MySQL queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, child-process

My intention is upon a file upload the main Node.JS process will fork a child process which will parse the uploaded file and then make bulk (1K+) MySQL queries. I want the child to handle the queries because I do not want the parent process to "block." Since both the parent and child processes need access to the MySQL connection I have defined in an external file containing an npm MySQL pool:

`mysqlConnector.js`:

```js
// Load module
var mysql = require('mysql');
// Initialize pool
var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'bob',
    password: 'my_pass',
    database: 'my_db'
});    

const doQuery = (query_string) => {
  console.log(pool);
  pool.query(query_string, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('in doQuery: query' );
  });
};

exports.doQuery = doQuery;
exports.pool = pool
```

I am able to import both the pool and the `doQuery` method into my main Express `index.js` and use them with no issue:

`index.js`:

```js
const {doQuery, pool} = require('./mysqlConnector');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const { username, password } = req.query;

    const GET_USER_QUERY = `select username, password from users where username = '${username}' and password = '${password}'`;
    doQuery(GET_USER_QUERY); //logically insignificant function call but wanted to verify doQuery works from here
    console.log(pool);
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            throw err;
        }   
        connection.query(GET_USER_QUERY, (err, results) => {
            if(!err) {
                console.log(results);
                connection.release();
                return res.json(results);
            }           
            else{
                console.log(err);
                connection.release();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works fine for using `mysqlConnector.js` in `index.js`, however, the forked child process can successfully import and "see" the pool object from `mysqlConnector.js` but it "doesn't work" when the child process attempts to use the exported pool or `doQuery` function.

Here is the chunk of code from `index.js` that will fork a child:

`index.js`

```js
app.post('/upload', upload.single('thefile'), (req, res) => {
    const {username} = req.query;
    
    fileHandlerProcess = fork("./fileupload/handleprops.js");
    fileHandlerProcess.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(`PARENT: message from child process is ${msg}`);
        res.sendStatus(msg.status);
    });
    fileHandlerProcess.send({"filepath":`${__dirname}\\${req.file.path}`,"username":`${username}`});
});
```

And here is `handleprops.js`, the js file the forked child will run:

`handleprops.js`

```js
const {execSync, fork} = require('child_process');
const {doQuery} = require('../mysqlConnector');

const exec_options = {
    cwd: null,
    env: null,
    encoding: 'utf8',
    timeout: 0,
    maxBuffer: 200 * 1024,
    killSignal: 'SIGTERM'
};


process.on('message', msg=>{

  if(msg.filepath && msg.username){
    execSync(`java -jar C:\\Users\\colli\\d2reader\\out\\artifacts\\d2reader_jar\\d2reader.jar ${msg.filepath}`, exec_options);

    var filename = msg.filepath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    filename = __dirname + "\\json\\" + filename.substring(0, filename.length-3) + "json";
    try{
      const fs = require('fs');
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      processSharedStashQueries(JSON.parse(data), msg.username);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    process.exit();
  }
});

const processSharedStashQueries = (data, username) => {
    const INSERT_USER_QUERY = `insert into sharedstashes  (NumStashes, SharedGold, NumItems, UserID) values (${data.numStashes}, ${data.sharedGold}, ${data.numItems}, (select id from users where username = '${username}'))`;
    doQuery(INSERT_USER_QUERY);

};
```

When the child calls "doQuery()" the pool object will be logged and I can verify it is a valid and defined object and is the same exact pool object the parent process (index.js) uses. However, nothing happens when the child hits the "pool.query()" line of code. No error and no console logs. It's as if nothing happens.

Why can the child process "see" the pool object but not be able to use it?